I want to compute FFT and IFFT on a large image via GPU. But my GPU is low on memory
I’m working on a MATLAB project that requires FFT and IFFT computations on large images using GPUs. Currently, the image size is
32000×25600 with double precision data. Although we need to process even larger images, we’ve reduced the size due to GPU memory constraints.
We’re using two NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3080 GPUs (each with 9.51 GB of available memory) to accelerate the process. Below is a simplified version of our code:
**parpool('Processes', 2);
object = ones(32000, 25600, 'gpuArray');
objectFT = fftshift(fft2(object));**

However, this approach runs into GPU memory issues. I attempted to split the image into smaller chunks to manage memory better and wrote a function to divide the computation across two GPUs using spmd as shown below:
**function result = dualGPUFFT(image, chunkSize, inverse)
    [m, n] = size(image);
    result = zeros(m, n);
    spmd
        gpuDevice(labindex);
        disp(['Worker ', num2str(labindex), ' using GPU ', num2str(gpuDevice().Index)]);
        if labindex == 1
            localData = gpuArray(image(1:floor(m / 2), :)); % Top half
        else
            localData = gpuArray(image(floor(m / 2) + 1:end, :)); % Bottom half
        end
        localResult = gpuArray.zeros(size(localData), 'like', localData);
        numChunks = ceil(size(localData, 1) / chunkSize);
        for chunkIdx = 1:numChunks
            rowStart = (chunkIdx - 1) * chunkSize + 1;
            rowEnd = min(chunkIdx * chunkSize, size(localData, 1));
            chunk = localData(rowStart:rowEnd, :);
            if inverse
                chunkResult = ifft2(ifftshift(chunk));
            else
                chunkResult = fftshift(fft2(chunk));
            end
            localResult(rowStart:rowEnd, :) = chunkResult;
        end
        resultLocal = gather(localResult);
        if labindex == 1
            result(1:floor(m / 2), :) = resultLocal;
        else
            result(floor(m / 2) + 1:end, :) = resultLocal;
        end
    end
end**

Unfortunately, this approach also failed to handle the memory issue effectively.
Here are my key questions:
How can I efficiently manage GPU memory for FFT/IFFT computations on such large images?
Are there other chunking strategies or libraries that could handle this better in MATLAB?
Does performing FFT/IFFT on GPUs for large images generally offer significant speed improvements over CPUs?
I’d greatly appreciate any insights, recommendations, or alternative approaches for handling such large-scale FFT/IFFT computations.

In my experience, GPU FFT is not faster than a good multi-threaded CPU FFT. MATLAB's FFT is super fast.

To add on Ander's coment, the MATLAB fft2 is already using multithreading and is quite fast.

Thank you for your response.
I tried this code because the use of GPU is separate in the matlab fft2 code description.
If I use GPU instead of CPU when processing large-capacity images, wouldn't it be faster? I tried it with the thought, but I didn't know that there would be a small difference in speed between CPU FFT and GPU FFT.
Thank you for the good insight.
